# Auto resizing elements to prevent appearing of scrollbars

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a parent element where I want to show some images. Aspect ratio of all images will be the same and it is fixed for all images (say, it will 16:9 and it won't change).

I want to display images in a given parent element with centering them  vertically and horizontally. The trickiest part is that I want to resize images keeping their aspect ratio so there is no horizontal or vertical scrollbar when number of images is high enough. In other words: I want to see all images at the same time.

Comment: For us to be able to suggest a proper answer, we also need your HTML/CSS. (and if you don't have one, make one, as SO is not a code writing service)

Comment: Here's a [method using Flexbox](https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/msItD) and your [guide to CSS centering](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/) (CSS Tricks) which is the source of this pen. _Autoresizing_ is what happens by default with CSS as long as you don't set (max-)(width|height)

Comment: @FelipeAls the problem is not about centering, but about maintaining given aspect ratio

Comment: Your question is quite unclear - at least to me. Please provide some HTML/CSS and/or mock images